# How to speed up processing of a ~15mb html file

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, text-files, lxml

My goal is to **scrape** html page, and clean it up for further content analysis with pandas data frame. Problem is that this operation takes like forever, which is really uncomfortable since file has only ~15mb. To be honest I run out of patience after 3 or 4 hours and started reaserch. Do you have any idea how I can speed it up?

Here is my code and logic:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser
import pandas as pd
import re
```

urlib2 -> to get code from website

TextParser -> to parse scraped text into data frame

pandas -> to do later reaserch

```
parsed = lxml.html.parse(urlopen('http://somewebsite.com'))
doc = parsed.getroot()
```

Ok. So now I have my precious website. It went very well. But after that I want to **scrape** it a little. First I will search for column labels for data frame:

```
def header(css_style):

    head = doc.find_class(css_style)
    return [col.text_content() for col in head[:20]] <- it contains mostly every column label, and it ends on '20', because after that it will repeat several times in the file
col = header('CSS_style_that_I'm_looking_for')
```

So far so good. But next element of my code is executing forever. I thing that is mainly because it is running only in memory and must compute very big list... and after that two more. Do you see some place for improvement? (as you can see I'm not a python wizard and obviously there is better way that I don't see)

```
def _unpack(css_style, date_type):

    data = doc.find_class(css_style)
    start = [data.index(col) for col in data if date_type in col.text_content() and 'Time:' not in col.text_content()]
    return [[ col.text_content().encode('utf8', 'ignore') for col in data][start[i]:start[i+1]] for i in range(len(start)-1)]

  rows = _unpack('CSS_style_that_I'm_looking_for', 'Patter_for_scraping')
```

About code above: data looks for css_style. After that I have list of content, but I must group it. So start is looking for first string in my desire group. At the end this function returns list with lists of groups. Main reason why I did that is because content that I'm interested in is in the same css_classes.

I think that it's worth to mention that this html contains many html tables.

Maybe it will help to first save "data" content in some file(from _upack def) to loose some memory?

after that my code looks like that (which is for now not important, since code above takes so much time, that it was not executed yet - only earlier on some small sample of that html file)

```
# Adjusting number of columns to the longest list from _unpack operation

number_col = max([len(rows[i]) for i in range(len(rows))])

def col_adj():

    for i in range(number_col - len(col)):

    col.append('col'+str(i))

col_adj()

# creating data frame

table = TextParser(rows, names = col).get_chunk()

# cleaning data frame

def clearing_table(name):

    for x in range(len(table[name])):
        if table[name][x] is not None:

            try:
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].strip()
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('\t', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('\r', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('\n', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('?', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('\xc3','\xaf','\xc2','\xbf','\xc2','\xbd', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('colspan="14">', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('<b>', '')
                table[name][x] = table[name][x].replace('</b>\xa0', '')
            
            
            except:
                pass
            

def clearing_datatable():
    
    for x in col:
        clearing_table(x)            

clearing_datatable()

def time_series(name):

ts = []

    for x in range(len(table[name])):

        ts.append(table[name][x][:19].encode('utf8', 'ignore'))    
    table['time_series'] = ts
    table['time_series'] = table['time_series'].astype('datetime64[ns]')


time_series('Time')


def duration(name):

    duration = []
    for x in range(len(table[name])):            
        minutes = table[name][x][:table[name][x].index('m')].encode('utf8', 'ignore')
        minutes = int(minutes)*60        
        seconds = table[name][x][table[name][x].index('m')+2:table[name][x].index('s')].encode('utf8', 'ignore')      
        duration.append(int(minutes) + int(seconds))

table['duration_time'] = duration

duration('Duration')

#Saving everything to CSV file via Pandas

table.to_csv('database.csv')
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap